# XTerm working but not Terminal?

Tags: command-line

So to begin with, my Ubuntu installation functions properly and everything runs without throwing errors. However, whenever I try to bring up a terminal window, it just loads a blank black screen with no text and I'm unable to enter commands. Furthermore, whenever I try to drop into the Terminal via Ctrl + Alt + F1 , it shows a blank screen as well. The most boggling part to me, is that not only does the XWindows set up work fine, not only does XTerm work fine, but when I go into recovery mode the root console works fine. I tried reinstalling gnome-terminal to see if it would fix anything, but it doesn't fix anything. Any other suggestions? I've tried searching to see if there was any other cases of this, but everyone else seems to get theirs working by hitting Ctrl + C, which also does not fix mine.

EDIT: Correction, Ctrl + Alt + F1 brings up terminal, but it is still blank. Ctrl + Alt + F7 returns me to GUI